# Is this Mulberry stem still alive

Tags: propagation, mulberry

Below is a picture of a stem from a particular tree that I have propagated mulberries in the past. The tree is in a different city than where I am now.

I know I should have cut a thicker stem, but had to rush the process due to being late for my train.

Anyway, I have been watering this for two weeks now. Another stem that I cut at the same time, but thicker and gifted to my neighbor, has put out a leaf.

Just wondering whether I should continue to keep watering or is it completely dead and not worth the effort.

[image: y]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colour of it indicates that it still is alive.

See the difference of colour at the top? It should look a little orange if it were dead.

Same for the buds, which are a little green.

I advise you be patient, it should sprout leaves if weather doesn't get too dry and too hot soon.

Comment: So does that mean the top of my stem is dead and the leaves, if any, may sprout from the bottom? Should I be watering it everyday? It is summer, but I believe the hottest days are behind us. Just concerned about the thickness of the stem

Comment: Not sure the top bud is dead. It could sprout from that one or the below. Not sure what the needs are in your part of the world. It also depends on how deep the stem  is inside the ground, and what sort of soil you put around it. Just keeping the soil moist should be enough. I am not concerned about the thickness of the stem. From the colour I see, there is life in there, there still is a chance it lives and grows.